# opencv2 Aruco library modules not working with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, aruco

I have compiled the aruco library as stated here [github link for aurco library](https://github.com/fehlfarbe/python-aruco)

I have checked it has compiled successfully as i can import it in python without any error and to check i have run the example.py script also it's working but when i wrote this code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import aruco



Dictionary = aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(aruco.PREDEFINED_DICTIONARY_NAME(DICT_5X5_250=6))

aruco.drawMarker(Dictionary,5,250,markerImage,1)
aruco.drawMarker(Dictionary,10,250,markerImage,1)
aruco.drawMarker(Dictionary,20,250,markerImage,1)
aruco.drawMarker(Dictionary,25,250,markerImage,1)
aruco.drawMarker(Dictionary,50,250,markerImage,1)
aruco.drawMarker(Dictionary,100,250,markerImage,1)
aruco.drawMarker(Dictionary,200,250,markerImage,1)

cv2.imshow("markers",markerImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imgwrite(marker.jpg,markerImage)
```

it throws error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "drawmarker.py", line 7, in
>   
>       Dictionary = aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(aruco.PREDEFINED_DICTIONARY_NAME(DICT_5X5_250=6))
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
>   'getPredefinedDictionary'

can someone please let me know what am i doing wrong, is this module not imported in python version of aruco ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should try this "aruco.DICT_5X5_250" as parameter, like...

`dict = aruco.getPredefinedDictionary( aruco.DICT_5X5_250 )`

it worked for me :)